# Using lib CountUp.js on Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

How do I correctly use the CountUp.js lib in Yii2? 
I already added it in `AppAsset` and it loaded correctly in View, now I would assign the use of lib and a number displayed in that same view

**AppAsset.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/custom-bootstrap.css',
        'css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css',          
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/countup.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Could someone give me an example of use in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the javascript version of the library for `countUp.js` you need to create a new instance of the `CountUp(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options)` with the configuration parameters and then call `instance.start();` to start the counter.

#### Params:

> - `target` = id of html element, input, svg text element, or var of previously selected element/input where counting occurs
> - `startVal` = the value you want to begin at
> - `endVal` = the value you want to arrive at
> - `decimals` = (optional) number of decimal places in number, default 0
> - `duration` = (optional) duration in seconds, default 2
> - `options` = (optional, see demo) formatting/easing options object

[Read More](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/blob/master/README.md)

I assume that you have already registered the above `AppAsset` class and the source library is loaded otherwise uncomment the CDN link for the `countUp.js` on top of the view below, copy the following view and run it

```
<?php
    use yii\web\View;

    //$this->registerJsFile('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countup@1.8.2/dist/countUp.min.js');

    $js = <<<JS
    var options = {
      useEasing: true,
      useGrouping: true,
      separator: ',',
      decimal: '.',
    };
    var demo = new CountUp('counter', 0, 5220, 0, 2.5, options);
    if (!demo.error) {
      demo.start();
    } else {
      console.error(demo.error);
    }
JS;
    $this->registerJs($js, View::POS_END);

?>

<div id="counter">

</div>
```

Comment: I was instantiating wrong CountUp, and besides the .js file that I downloaded was with some error, I used this countUp.min.js and gave it right. Thank you for teaching me how to use it correctly. ^